# Why should I use log.Println instead of fmt.Println?

Tags: logging, go

From [log.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/log/log.go) (the implementation of the log package) :

```
167 // Println calls l.Output to print to the logger.
168 // Arguments are handled in the manner of fmt.Println.
169 func (l *Logger) Println(v ...interface{}) { l.Output(2, fmt.Sprintln(v...)) }
```

[`log.Println`](http://golang.org/pkg/log/#Println) is just a function wrapper for [`fmt.Sprintln`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintln) , why should I use it instead of [`fmt.Println`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) or [`fmt.Sprintln`](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintln) ?

Any practical reasons ?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Two things are different:

1. Printing via package log is safe from concurrent goroutines (while plain `fmt` isn't)
2. Log can add timing information automatically.

So these are two completely different things. log is for logging and `fmt` for formatting. (Okay, log uses the same verbs and flags, but that is just convenient).

Comment: I like Log because of the timestamp. The downside to using Log is that it always writes to stderr.

Comment: @rem7 it logs to `os.Stderr` by *default*. Simply call [`log.SetOutput`](https://golang.org/pkg/log/#SetOutput) to send it to any `io.Writer` (which might even be a `bytes.Buffer`).

Comment: For discussions around the safety of `log` and `fmt` in goroutines, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694088/is-it-safe-for-more-than-one-goroutine-to-print-to-stdout