# When to use log over fmt for debugging and printing error?

Tags: go

I know that we can print variable or error using `log` and `fmt`. for example if I want to print variable I can do this :

```
h := "world"
fmt.Printf("hello = %v\n", h)
log.Printf("halo = %v\n", h)
```

the output would be :

```
hello = world
2016/12/30 09:13:12 halo = world
```

and usually in the error handling I found log like this

```
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error : something terrible happen -> ", err)
    return err
}
```

but from above case I could also use `fmt` to print the error like this

```
fmt.Printf("Error : something terrible happen -> %v\n",err.Error())
```

Is it a good practice to use `fmt` instead of `log` for printing the error?
And then I always use `fmt` instead of `log` for printing the variable when debugging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use log.Println instead of fmt.Println?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646889/why-should-i-use-log-println-instead-of-fmt-println)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Select between `log` and `fmt` using these facts:

- The `log` functions print to [stderr](https://godoc.org/os#Stderr) by default and can [directed to an arbitrary writer](https://godoc.org/log#SetOutput). The `fmt.Printf` function prints to [stdout](https://godoc.org/os#Stdout).
- The `log` functions can [print timestamp, source code location and other info](https://godoc.org/log#pkg-constants).
- The `log` functions and `fmt.Printf` are both thread safe, but concurrent writes by `fmt.Printf` above an OS dependent size can be interleaved.

The answer to the three sub questions are "it depends".

Comment: Could show me an example about `The log functions can print timestamp, source code location and other info.` ?

Comment: @BlackMamba It looks like this but is happens automatically when you use log: `Dec 16 16:13:20 My-MacBook someDescription[80590]: 2019/12/16 16:13:20 Error 1054: Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 14):

I would like to add one more point:

- Log is thread safe where as fmt is not.

  A Logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines; it guarantees to serialize access to the Writer.

[Link](https://godoc.org/log#Logger)

Comment: how do you know if `log` is thread safe? any reference for this ? thanks

Comment: @GujaratSantana The [logger documentation](https://godoc.org/log#Logger) states that a logger can be used simultaneously from multiple goroutines.  There is no documentation on the thread safety of `fmt.Printf`.  The `fmt.Printf` implementation is thread safe it is very unlikely that it will be changed to not be thread safe.

Comment: Actually, though `fmt.Printf` is thread safe in the sense that it doesn't have any data races, a `Logger` uses a mutex to serialize the output, while fmt writes it out directly. With enough concurrency you can get interleaved writes to stdout.

Answer (score 7):

You generally don't get into trouble if you stick to use fmt.Print* for program **output** and log.* for program **logging**.

Of course if your program doesn't have "local" output (as most network server programs) you could use both for logging, but for logging log.* is more flexible and apt.

Answer (score 4):

From "[Essential Go](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/go/logging-f7fca2011c3748a19e3b8d66235cbe59)" book

Standard package [log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) offers more functionality:

```
log.Printf("Logging")
log.Printf("Second line\n")

2019/03/26 10:07:11 Logging
2019/03/26 10:07:11 Second line
```

Compared to fmt.Printf, log.Printf:

- By default logs to stderr (os.Stderr)
- Adds current time to each log line
- Ensures that echo log is on it’s own line by adding \n if not explicitly provided

To log fatal issues:

```
f, err := os.Open("file.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("os.Open('file.txt') failed with '%s'\n", err)
}
```

log.Fatalf logs the message and calls os.Exit(1) to end the process.