# Resolving conflicts with goroutines?

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a really minor doubt
Suppose there are three func A,B,C
C is being called from both A and B
I am running A and B on different threads , will it result in conflict any time in feature when it calls C within it

for reference i am adding this code

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func xyz() {
     for true {
         fmt.Println("Inside xyz")
         call("xyz")
     }
}

func abc() {
    for true {
         fmt.Println("Inside abc")
         call("abc")
    }
}

func call(s string) {
    fmt.Println("call from " + s)
}

func main() {
    go xyz()
    go abc()
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

Here A = xyz(), B = abc(), C = call()

will there be any conflict or any runtime error in future while running these two go routines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether multiple goroutines are safe to run concurrently or not comes down to whether they share data without synchronization. In this example, both `abc` and `xyz` print to `stdout` using `fmt.Println`, and call the same routine, `call`, which prints to `stdout` using `fmt.Println`. Since [`fmt.Println` doesn't use synchronization when printing to `stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14694088/641955), the answer is no, this program is not safe.

Comment: what if i am not printing anything to stdout and instead doing something like downloading a file ?

Comment: As long as the two methods don't access shared data, they can be safe

Comment: My function is sharing a database variable which helps to connect to different tables in the database , but a call from any function access only a particular table in the database other that what other functions are accessing

Comment: This is starting to look like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... Methods accessing shared data can be safe if they use synchronization. Database that allow concurrent access use synchronization, so yes, you can probably use a database safely by concurrent goroutines.